# htaccess and Laravel

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

my domain

```
example.com
```

I  want install Laravel to subfolder

```
example.com/my_app
```

when I pass the link 
`example.com/my_app/public` - I see page "You have arrived", but I want see this page  without segment "public".

I want make something like I do when I use Laravel not in subfolder, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I edited .htaccass file in base folder (example.com) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my_app
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ my_app/public/$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

after this when I pass at `example.com/my_app/` I redirects to `example.com/my_app/public` and I see page "You have arrived", but this is redirect (R=301) and if I delete flag R=301 - I see page with "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I am three days  looking  solutions in this website, but ...

tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry point for all requests to a Laravel application is the public/index.php.

for further info you can go to this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/lifecycle#lifecycle-overview).

Assuming you are using Apache, You would need to configure virtual host for this as you would need to point ***example.com/my_app*** to your ***laravel/public/index.php***. directory.

Comment: I need that all request redirect with help htaccess from 
example.com/my_app to
 
example.com/my_app/public

I want make something like this:
"RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]"